# More efficiently writing partitioned parquet when partitioning column is skewed

Tags: sql, apache-spark, partitioning, skew

I'm working on writing a large table (approximately 1.2b rows) in partitioned parquet, I'm using state (like US state) as the partitioning key. The issue is that there is a large number of null state values. This table is often queried by state, so having a large partition with the null states is not an issue, but I'm having trouble more efficiently generating the table.

I've tried creating the table with the non-null states, then inserting the null, but from what I can tell all the null values still just get put in one big partition and therefore sent to one worker.

It would be great if there was a way to insert into a specific partition. Like for my example, write the non-null states, then insert remaining records into the state=null or hive_default_partition in a way that would still parallelize across the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing the non-null data using automatic partitioning, then repartition the null data and write it separately, e.g.:

```
df.where($”state”.isNotNull).write.partitionBy($”state”).parquet(“my_output_dir”)
df.where($”state”.isNull).repartition(100).write.parquet(“my_output_dir/state=__HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION__”)
```

Using the SQL API, you can use a repartitioning hint (introduced in Spark 2.4) to accomplish the same:

```
spark-sql> describe skew_test;  
id  bigint  NULL
dt  date    NULL
state   string  NULL
# Partition Information     
# col_name  data_type   comment
state   string  NULL
Time taken: 0.035 seconds, Fetched 6 row(s)
spark-sql> CREATE TABLE `skew_test2` (`id` BIGINT, `dt` DATE, `state` STRING)
         > USING parquet
         > OPTIONS (
         >   `serialization.format` '1'
         > )
         > PARTITIONED BY (state);
Time taken: 0.06 seconds
spark-sql> insert into table skew_test2  select * from skew_test where state is not null;
Time taken: 1.208 seconds
spark-sql> insert into table skew_test2  select /*+ REPARTITION(100) */ * from skew_test where state is  null;
Time taken: 1.39 seconds
```

You should see 100 tasks created by Spark for the final statement, and your `state=__HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION__` directory should contain 100 parquet files. For more information on Spark-SQL hints, check out https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-hint-framework.html#specifying-query-hints

Comment: I am, unfortunately, working in a SQL codebase that I can't update at this time. So this solution may work, but I'm having trouble translating it into SQL.

As a side question though, since the columns appear removed when you partition (e.g. if you read the file in state=FL directly, it doesn't have a state column. That appears inferred from the partitioning when you read the full directory), would you need to drop the state column before writing directly to that default partition?

Comment: I’ll edit the answer to show how to do this via Spark-SQL. In my first example using the Dataset API, you do not necessarily need to remove `state`, but you’re correct in that it’d be a good idea to. In SQL, you do indeed need to remove the column, as my example will reflect.